# Get POST data from WebKitNetworkRequest

Tags: python, webkit

I am trying to send data from a javascript app running in GTK webkit to Python via a HTTP request with the data sent in POST.

I can capture the request using `resource-request-starting` and checking the uri of the request.

I know the request works because I can send data through the request headers and view it with

```
def on_resource_request_starting(view, frame, resource, request, response):
    uri = urllib.unquote(request.props.uri)
    if uri.startswith('http://appname.local/'):
        print request.get_message().request_headers.get_one('foobar')
```

But when I use `print request.get_message().request_body.data` I don't get anything.

How do I  view the POST data?

Comment: Please post the answer if you will find it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this API, but I believe you need to call the binding's equivalent of `soup_message_body_flatten()` before reading the `data` field. See the documentation for [`SoupMessageBody`](http://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupMessageBody.html#SoupMessageBody-struct) in the C API.

So, at a guess:

```
print request.get_message().request_body.flatten().data
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooking to SoupSession "request-queued" signal and getting
buffer(s) using soup_message_body_get_chunk(soupmsgbody, num);
seems to work (in webkitgtk1 today, Jun 2015).
webkit_get_default_session() returns the SoupSession in question.